# Puppet: Apache proxy + basic Auth

Tags: apache, authentication, proxy, puppet, mod-proxy

I'm trying to create an Apache config with puppet which in includes reverse proxying and basic authentication.

My approach looks like

```
apache::vhost { 'domain.tld':                                                                                                                                                                                                       
 port    => '80',                                                                                                                                                                  
 proxy_pass => {
  path => '/',
  url => 'http://10.10.10.20:19999/'
 },
 docroot => '/var/www/html',
 directories => [                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
  {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
   path => '/',                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
   auth_type => 'Basic',                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
   auth_name => 'Basic Auth',                                                                                                                                                                                                                    auth_user_file => '/etc/apache2/.htpasswd-netdata',                                                                                                                                                                                       
   auth_require => "valid-user",                                                                                                                                                                                                                },
 ],
}
```

This creates a config file like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName domain.tld

  ## Vhost docroot
  DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"

  ## Proxy rules
  ProxyRequests Off
  ProxyPreserveHost Off
  ProxyPass / http://10.10.10.20:19999/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://10.10.10.20:19999/
  <Directory "/">
      AllowOverride None
      Require valid-user
      AuthType Basic
      AuthName "Basic Auth"
      AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/.htpasswd
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

but this doesn't work and it should rather look like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName domain.tld

  ## Vhost docroot
  DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"

  ## Proxy rules
  ProxyRequests Off
  ProxyPreserveHost Off
  ProxyPass / http://10.10.10.20:19999/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://10.10.10.20:19999/
  <Proxy *>
      AllowOverride None
      Require valid-user
      AuthType Basic
      AuthName "Basic Auth"
      AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/.htpasswd
  </Proxy>
</VirtualHost>
```

Does anyone know how to setup basic auth in combination with a proxy in puppet?

Answer (score 0):

had the same problem...

You just need to add in the directory block a "provider" and set this to "proxy".

Looks like:

```
directories => [
      {
        provider => 'proxy',
        path     => '*'
        ...
```

Also work if you set provider to "location" instead of proxy. But if you need proxy, just set the provider to proxy.